# How to use findElement(By.cssSelector("")) in Visual Studio in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to use

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("....."));
```

But it doesn't work(cannot use the FindElement with By). Do you know what can replace it? I'm using visual studio 2019 and write in C#

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WebDriverTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.marketinginternetdirectory.com/submit.php");

            //Find form element to auto fill on form page - Right click on input->inspect
            var title_field = driver.FindElement(By.)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting a compiler error? Are you getting an exception at runtime? Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: visual studio are not recognize "By" and i can't complete the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "are not recognize"? It doesn't show up in Intellisense? If you simply type "By" in C#, does it underline that text in red and show a compiler error?

Comment: You probably need `using OpenQA.Selenium;` at the top of your C# file.

Comment: Put your text cursor on the same line that has the word "By". Press **Ctrl** + **.** (literally the "period" key). It will bring up suggested fixes. The first suggestion will add the 'using' statement to the top of your C# file.

Comment: Hello, method: "driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("....."));, does it not work. Is the requirement to click the button to return the backend data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

For your specific example you can locate title by doing this:

```
var titleElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name = 'TITLE']"));

// And if you want to go a step further you might after want to do something like this:
element.SendKeys("YOUR-TITLE");
```

Comment: It work just when i write like this: var title_field = driver.FindElement(OpenQA.Selenium.By.XPath("........"));

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in [`By Class`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_By.htm) the notations is as follows:

- **`CssSelector`**: Gets a mechanism to find elements by their cascading style sheet (CSS) selector.

Your effective line of code will be:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

var title_field = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("svg g rect:nth-child(20)"));
```

---

### Reference

[Selenium C# Webdriver Tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html)